# Restore Default sources.list on Ubuntu EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have crashed my `sources.list` file on an Ubuntu EC2 system.
Is there a way, without reinstalling it, to get the `sources.list` back?
I tried to find a copy with Google, but had no luck. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest: spin up another instance from the same AMI and copy it from there. A tiny one like `t3.nano` will cost you a fraction of a cent for the few minutes that you’ll need it for.

Hope that helps :)